# Insert the value of column in another column as jsonb

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to insert the value of one column as the value for another column of type jsonb, so this is what I currently have:

```sql
INSERT INTO "Customers" ("id", "priceList", "metadata")
SELECT
  id,
  priceList as Price,
  metadata as Others,
  json_build_object('id',id,'Price',Price,'Others',Others) as jsonField
FROM "CustomersCopel"
```

but it doesn't work as you can see what I want is add the results of id, priceList and metadata in the jsonb column called 'jsonField'

this is the version of postgres I'm running: 
`PostgreSQL 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit`

Comment: Without CREATE TABLE statements, we can't very well see that it doesn't work, as it hard to run it in the first place.  I can see, though, that you are trying to select 4 columns and put the results into 3 columns.  Where is the constructed jsonField supposed to go?  There is no column specified to hold it.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a valid Postgres error message